# android set imagebutton in a tablerow

Tags: android, center, imagebutton

I have a ImageButton in a TableLayout/TableRow.

I would like to spread the ImageButton over the complete TableRow and set the pic
in the center of the button (height like the tablerow/button height)

I set in the layoutfile ...

```
 <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TableRow >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/CarPic"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:onClick="onButtonClick"
         android:scaleType="centerInside"
         android:src="@drawable/etype" />
```

```
 </TableLayout>
```

When the app starts the default pic appears like I described -
but when I Change with onclick the pic of the button ...
the button resizes to the pic height/width an stays in the right top Corner

Code for that

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(Path);
    LPic.setImageDrawable(d);
```

I have tried many different versions :( of fill and wrap but 
the button changes every picture

Comment: I have this problem, Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.You have to define weight property for this

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TableRow>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CarPic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, width is now working :) Thank you but ... not height ... layout_height = fill parent doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for both height and width

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/CarPic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TableRow>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/CarPic"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```